# JavaScript - How to find x,y position of element by key in a linear array of elements that are displayed as a square/matrix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, matrix, formula

I have this array of values:

```
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'];
```

Visually represented as a matrix:

```
a  b  c  d
e  f  g  h
i  j  k  l
m  n  o  p
```

What I want to do - if I'm given any **key** of this array and the **length of the array**, to calculate the row & column value `[x,y]`.

- `0` (*a*) of `16` (*array length*) would be `[0,0]`
- `6` (*g*) of `16` (*array length*) would be `[1,2]`
- `13` (*n*) of `16` (*array length*) would be `[3, 1]`
- etc.

I'm iterating the array values in a `for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` loop to display them as tiles in a container. I could calculate each value's `[x,y]` position in that loop inline, or use a function to do so - doesn't really matter.

I'm stuck ..

```js
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'];
var size  = 100 / Math.sqrt(array.length);

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
  tile = document.createElement('div');
  
  tile.innerHTML        = array[i] + ' [x,y]';
  tile.style.width      = size+'%';
  tile.style.height     = size+'%';
  tile.style.float      = 'left';
  tile.style.background = 'rgb('+(50+i*5)+','+(150+i*5)+',200)';
  
  document.getElementById('square').appendChild(tile);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="square" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculate the width (or height) in advance, then use `i % width` and `Math.floor(i / width)` to figure out the current `x` and `y` position. (Also, when you're assigning *text*, make sure to assign to `textContent` and not `innerHTML`, and try not to implicitly create global variables)

```js
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'];
const width = Math.sqrt(array.length);
var size  = 100 / width;


for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
  const tile = document.createElement('div');
  const x = i % width;
  const y = Math.floor(i / width);
  
  tile.textContent        = `${array[i]} [${x},${y}]`;
  tile.style.width      = size+'%';
  tile.style.height     = size+'%';
  tile.style.float      = 'left';
  tile.style.background = 'rgb('+(50+i*5)+','+(150+i*5)+',200)';
  
  document.getElementById('square').appendChild(tile);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="square" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid;"></div>
```

Comment: I wasted more time writing this question than you took answering it... One love.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the maximum column first, in your case it's 4. As updated in code follows:

```
var maxCol = 4;
```

The for each increment of `i` use the calculation:

```
  x = Math.floor(i / maxCol);
  y = i % maxCol;
```

```js
var array = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p'];
var size  = 100 / Math.sqrt(array.length);
var maxCol = 4;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    
  tile = document.createElement('div');
  x = Math.floor(i / maxCol);
  y = i % maxCol;
  tile.innerHTML        = array[i] + ' ['+ x + ',' +　y +　']';
  tile.style.width      = size+'%';
  tile.style.height     = size+'%';
  tile.style.float      = 'left';
  tile.style.background = 'rgb('+(50+i*5)+','+(150+i*5)+',200)';
  
  tile = document.getElementById('square').appendChild(tile);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="square" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid;"></div>
```